# ionic list shows bad styling

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, styling

I have a `list` in `ionic` that uses `item-thumbnail-right` and `item-icon-left` classes

```
<div class="list">
     <a ng-repeat="item in vm.List track by $index"
                           class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right">
     <img on-error-src="{{vm.serverPath}}/Uploads/ErrorImages/imageErrorOrg.png" ng-src="{{vm.serverPath}}{{item.ImageUrl}}">
     <h2  style="color:gray">{{ item.Name}}</h2>
     <i class="icon ion-person-stalker ionicon" style="color:lightgreen" ng-if="item.IsFollowing" ng-click="toggleFollow(item)"></i>
     </a>
</div>
```

The problem is that it shows wrong styling on some devices:

[image]

When tried on iphone devices, it works fine:

[image]

How do I fix this problem? Is it an issue with the `list` class?

UPDATE: I have tried using `ion-list` but same problem

Answer (score 1):

I create ionic lists this way:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
   <img ng-src="{{item.img}}">
   <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
   <p>{{item.description}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and have no styling problem.

**update**

seems ok in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONbexb), but maybe in your case you have to write specific rules for some platforms, check [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-platform-ios-and-platform-cordova-css-classes/5898/15).